# Can aliases be used in a SQL delete query?

Tags: mysql, sql, alias, sql-delete

I have the following SQL query:

```
DELETE FROM table_b b WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_a a WHERE a.some_id = b.some_id)
```

and am getting the following error:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'b WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table_a a WHERE a.some_id =
>   b.some_id)' at line 1

this seems to suggest that aliases cannot be used with SQL delete statements (?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your query correctly and your wanting to delete all records that are not in table a from table b. A cleaner way to write it might be

```
DELETE FROM table_b WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table_a)
```

Comment: I like this approach as it avoids using a correlated subquery.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Comment: Regarding what Saharsh wrote, wouldn't this have an error, because of the lack of the alias b between DELETE and FROM? (you could now just remove the alias altogether, or mix in Saharsh's solution)

Comment: Yes your right I've updated and removed the alias think it makes it cleaner overall.

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can use alias in **DELETE** query. Just you have use that alias after DELETE keyword than it will work. It specifies that from which table you have delete the records.

Try this:

```
DELETE b 
FROM table_b b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_a a WHERE a.some_id = b.some_id)
```

Comment: This should probably be the selected answer since EXISTS clauses are often more effective than the other suggested answers.